# is there any code to get the number of pages of an article?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a web page (let's say a google page) with content:
if i want to get more of the same content i have to go to the next page.
Is there any Python function that could enable me to retrieve the number of pages of the article and the URL of each page ?

For example, in google, pages of a single request are given at the bottom 
[image: pages of a request]

I want to create a Python code that could retrieve the number of pages and the URL of each one.
Can you help please ?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

no, there is not such a thing in Python or any other programing language because every website implements differently the pagination, of course, some may have the same implementation but usually not

base on every web site you have to figure out how the pagination it is implemented you have to write custom code to

> retrieve the number of pages and the URL of each one